# how to run/build a simple timer without using setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I can't figure out how to build a javascript function that mimic setTimeout() but without using setTimeout/Interval. Is it possible?

Comment: No, but even if it was, why would you? edit: Not easily - you could potentially use `performance.now()`, but my question remains, why?

Comment: What is the actual problem that you are trying to solve?

Comment: Using a webworker.  but it would be laggy and messy.  webworkers work individually of the page, so if you have an infinite loop, it wont't  break your page

Comment: @paul: because of Page Visibility API - related problems. I know of solutions like jquery-visibility but I'd prefer building a standalone timer. Anyway, probably I'm just worring for nothing really important. Got to think.

Comment: If you do choose to roll your own mechanism for assessing page visibility, I'd very much recommend using `setTimeout/setInterval` to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame) and count cycles or time difference.